# regex - retrieve text between delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
1) there is a problem 2) There appears to be a bug 3) stuck on start screen.
```

I want to get the text after the `1)`, `2)` and `3)`. This is what I am looking for:

```
['there is a problem', 'There appears to be a bug', 'stuck on start screen']
```

I tried using `re.split` and split on `\d+`, but that doesn't give me what I want. I want to keep the solution generic, so if in case there is a `4)` or `5)` or more I can still retrieve the text.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try splitting on `r"\d+\)\s*"`. See http://ideone.com/oq9RRL. Or http://ideone.com/HJUP3J

Comment: @stribizhev Why don't you post an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regex ([see regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fP4yO4/1)):

```
\d+\)\s*
```

It matches:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\)` - a literal `)`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace symbols.

See [the code demo](http://ideone.com/HJUP3J)

```
import re
s = "1) there is a problem 2) There appears to be a bug 3) stuck on start screen.";
print ([x for x in re.split(r"\d+\)\s*", s) if x]);
# => ['there is a problem ', 'There appears to be a bug ', 'stuck on start screen.']
```

Comment: I was working on something like this...:( ..you surpassed me ... ;)

Comment: Actually, this will not work if there are `digits`+`)` inside the bullet items, but I guess it is not in scope of the current question.

Comment: you mean `+` character ?

Comment: :) No, just a sequuence of 1 or more digits followed by a literal closing round bracket

Comment: You mean something like `10) some_string` ?...because I tried myself and it works fine

Comment: What's up with those semicolons?

Comment: @IronFist No, he means `1) there is a p432)roblem 2) There a...`. This problem could be solved by just keeping a count and ensuring that the matching `\d+` is one more than the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list_of_strings = string.split(")")
for x in list_of_strings:
    x[:-1].append(new_list)
```

Comment: This would require a call to `strip` if the whitespace after `#)` is to be removed. I would rather go for a regex for readability.